# SQL - MAX GROUP BY, Include Additional Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

I have a table of purchases in the following format (simplified):

| tDate | tAmount | tDesription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1.50 | Ice Cream |
| 2021-01-01 | 1.60 | Pencils |
| 2021-02-03 | 4.50 | Paper |
| 2021-02-04 | 2.50 | Staples |

I'm trying to find the MAX() value of a purchase for each month, simple enough, but I can't seem to include additional columns in the result set from the row selected as the max. The output I'm looking for is:

| tDate | tMonth | tYear | tAmount | tDesription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | January | 2021 | 1.60 | Pencils |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | February | 2021 | 4.50 | Paper |

My thoughts where that I would add in a start of the month column for each row, group by that, and apply the MAX() to the amount, along with a date filter, which works, also had to apply the `tMonth` and `tYear` in the group by.

What I've tried is:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0, [tDate]),0), FORMAT([tDate], 'MMMM') as 'Month', FORMAT([tdate], 'yyyy') as 'Year', MAX([tAmount]) as 'tAmount'

-- Source Table
FROM t

-- Last X months
WHERE [tDate] >= DATEADD(month, -6, getDate())

-- Group by the month
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0, [tDate]),0), FORMAT([tDate], 'MMMM'), FORMAT([tDate], 'yyyy')

-- Order
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0, [tDate]),0) DESC
```

Which gives me something very close, but as soon as I add the `[tDescription]` column I'll receive the `'column not included in aggregate or group by'` error, and I obviously can't include the column in the group by, otherwise I'll end up with a row for each.

So I'm pretty stuck on the best approach to include the `[tDescription]` column in the results, and I've a feeling this query is flawed, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How do you define *which* description to take given you *are* aggregating rows?

Comment: Are you looking for the [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function?

Comment: Side note, `FORMAT` is a terribly show function. If you want the name of a month, use the `DATENAME` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(date), month(date) order by tAmount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

To include the name of the month, you can add `datename(month, date)`.  However, that seems redundant with the date column.